# How to recognize the combination of 2 character vectors as the name of a predefined vector

Tags: r, vector, character

R beginner here, so thanks in advance for your patience!

I'm trying to perform an operation and I don't think that I'm using the right approach in R.

Just to summarize what is written below - I want R to recognize the combination of 2 character vectors as the name of a predefined vector.

My dataset is:

```
Color <- c("Red", "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green")
Shade <- c("Burgundy", "Charcoal", "Azur", "Mustard", "Navy")
dataset <- data.frame(Color, Shade)
```

I have predefined vectors for "Redshades", "Blueshades" etc, to account for all shades of the colors. For example:

```
Redshades <- c("Burgundy", "Crimson", "Scarlet")
```

Now, I want to pass through each line of the dataset and identify if the shade corresponds to the color on the same row.

My approach was to take the name of the color in the 1st column, add "shades" to correspond to the name of the relevant vector which contains the shades names, and then compute if it was correct

```
col <- c(dataset$Color[1],"Shades", sep="")
```

The problem is that "col" returns a character, and not the vector name (which already exists). Using as.name() or noquote() doesn't help.

I accept that I may be way off target here, am open to any suggestions.....I've spent a while searching on stackoverflow and google but to no avail.......

Comment: For your example, this would be the solution `transform(dataset, Red = (Color == "Red") & (Shade %in% Redshades))`. For a more general problem, probably @beginneR approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R approach where you store your shades vectors in a list (I call it shadeslst).

```
Redshades <- c("Burgundy", "Crimson", "Scarlet")
Blueshades <- c("Azur", "Navy")
# add more shades ...

# store them in a list
shadeslst <- list(Red = Redshades, Blue = Blueshades)

shadeslst
#$Red
#[1] "Burgundy" "Crimson"  "Scarlet" 
#
#$Blue
#[1] "Azur" "Navy"
```

Now use `sapply` to check if they are in the equivalent list element:

```
dataset$check <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), function(idx) with(dataset, Shade[idx] %in% shadeslst[[as.character(Color[idx])]]))
```

Note that the list names have to correspond to the color names in `dataset$Color` for this to work.

```
dataset
#   Color    Shade check
#1    Red Burgundy  TRUE
#2    Red Charcoal FALSE
#3   Blue     Azur  TRUE
#4 Yellow  Mustard FALSE
#5  Green     Navy FALSE
```

Comment: You are no beginneR! Excellent, thanks a lot, had a feeling that lists would be involved. Still have to get my head around the working of the apply functions. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3828894, welcome, I also still find myself wondering what's the best `*apply`-function approach to doing some things from time to time. You'll get used to it. If you're happy with the solution, feel free to upvote/accept it - that's basically how you say thanks on SO.

Comment: I didn't realize that there was an accept button, just hit it now. Unfortunately, I can't vote yet, need to enhance my reputation!

Comment: @user3828894, no worries, it's all good - and thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing different shades in a list `shadeslst` as suggested by @beginneR, you could also do:

```
 library(qdap)
 library(reshape2) 
 dataset$check <- paste2(dataset) %in% paste2(melt(shadeslst)[,2:1])
 #instead of paste2 from qdap, you could use as.character(interaction(dataset))
 dataset
 #   Color    Shade check
 #1    Red Burgundy  TRUE
 #2    Red Charcoal FALSE
 #3   Blue     Azur  TRUE
 #4 Yellow  Mustard FALSE
 #5  Green     Navy FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you to verify if all the rows with red shades, are correctly labelled as red. All the blue shades as blue, etc. First step is to identify which rows belong to a certain shade. Using your Redshades example this is done in the following way;

```
is.red.shade <- dataset$Shade %in% Redshades
```

This returns a logical vector, which subsequently can be used to index the first column of the dataset.

```
dataset$Color[is.red.shade]
```

In this case you have only one value returned so you see that it is correct right away. If this returns a vector that is too long to inspect visually you could check if all values are red by

```
all(dataset$Color[is.red.shade] == "Red")
```

Hope this will resolve your problem, let me know if this is not quite it.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, a good solution, although I probably should have said that I have a long list of colors, so having to go through them individually would take some time. I like a lot the solution of beginneR below, it works great for me.